# VagrantPlugins::SoftLayer::Errors::SLApiError

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We ran into this issue while provisioning VMs using vagrant softlayer plugin.

> [EnvInject] - Inject global passwords.
>   09:38:03 [EnvInject] - Mask passwords that will be passed as build parameters.
>   09:38:03 [workspace] $ /bin/bash /tmp/hudson4249446037328341553.sh
>   09:38:06 Bringing machine 'base02' up with 'softlayer' provider...
>   09:38:06 ==> base02: Creating a new SoftLayer instance...
>   09:38:12 Vagrant returned an exception while calling the SoftLayer API.
>   09:38:12
>   09:38:12 Exception class: VagrantPlugins::SoftLayer::Errors::SLApiError
>   09:38:12 Exception message: Vagrant returned an exception while calling the softLayer API.
>   09:38:12
>   09:38:12 Exception class: Errno::ECONNRESET
>   09:38:12 Exception message: Connection reset by peer**
>   09:38:12 --- Failed to provision base02
>   09:38:12 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
>   09:38:12 No emails were triggered.
>   09:38:12 Finished: FAILURE

Above message comes from executing the code block below:

```
vagrant up base02 --provider=softlayer --no-provision   
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then   
  echo --- Failed to provision base02   
  exit 1   
fi
```

We also tried calling the REST API directly, but still failing to spin up VMs:

```
curl -X POST --data @jenkinsCreateVM-BaseOS.json https://${SL_USERNAME}:${SL_API_KEY}@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObje
```

See below message for output:

> 09:38:03 [EnvInject] - Inject global passwords.
>   09:38:03 [EnvInject] - Mask passwords that will be passed as build parameters.
>   09:38:03 [workspace] $ /bin/bash /tmp/hudson8999395858193986552.sh
>   09:38:03 traceroute to api.softlayer.com (66.228.119.120), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
>   09:38:03  1  82.66.559e.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com (158.85.102.130)  0.744 ms 0.863 ms 83.66.559e.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com (158.85.102.131)  0.676 ms
>   09:38:03  2  ae6.dar01.tor01.networklayer.com (158.85.118.134)  5.891 ms     ae11.dar02.tor01.networklayer.com (158.85.118.132)  0.408 ms  0.367 ms
>   09:38:03  3  ae25.bbr01.cl01.tor02.networklayer.com (50.97.19.52)  1.160 ms     1.164 ms ae26.bbr01.cl01.tor02.networklayer.com (50.97.19.54)  1.112 ms
>   09:38:08  4  ae2.bbr02.eq01.chi01.networklayer.com (50.97.19.15)  11.452 ms 11.535 ms  11.452 ms
>   09:38:08  5  * * *
>   09:38:08  6  * * *
>   09:38:08  7  ae33.bbr02.eq01.dal03.networklayer.com (50.97.17.55)  30.951 ms  31.048 ms  31.093 ms
>   09:38:08  8  ae0.dar02.sr01.dal01.networklayer.com (173.192.18.253)  30.661 ms    ae1.dar02.sr01.dal01.networklayer.com (173.192.18.213)  31.889 ms  30.586 ms
>   09:38:08  9  * * *
>   09:38:08 10  * * *
>   09:38:08 11  * * *
>   09:38:13 12  * * *
>   09:38:13 13  * * *
>   09:38:13 14  * * *
>   09:38:13 15  * * *
>   09:38:13 16  * * *
>   09:38:18 17  * * *
>   09:38:18 18  * * *
>   09:38:18 19  * * *
>   09:38:18 20  * * *
>   09:38:18 21  * * *
>   09:38:23 22  * * *
>   09:38:23 23  * * *
>   09:38:23 24  * * *
>   09:38:23 25  * * *
>   09:38:23 26  * * *
>   09:38:23 27  * * *
>   09:38:28 28  * * *
>   09:38:28 29  * * *
>   09:38:28 30  * * *
>   09:38:28   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>   09:38:28                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>   09:38:28
>     0     0    0     0    0   550      0   2347 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2347
>     0     0    0     0    0   550      0   1250 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
>   **09:38:28 curl: (56) SSL read: errno -5961
>
>   09:38:28 --- No instance ID returned**
>   09:38:28 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
>   09:38:28 No emails were triggered.
>   09:38:28 Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

Well can you use directly the Softlayer API? I mean when you call a API method using curl does it work? if you get errors calling the API directly it may due to newtwroks connection issues in your side, and if you can use the api directly with no issue this is probably an issue wiht the vagrant plugin and I recomed you to submit the issue here https://github.com/audiolize/vagrant-softlayer/issues for further help.

Regards